# Wrong path when downloading in Backpack CRUD view

Tags: laravel, crud, laravel-5.6, laravel-backpack

i added an upload field in my CRUD Controller.
Upload works fine and file gets loaded in my /storage/private directory.

Here is filesystems.php file:

```
    'private' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('private')
    ],
```

Here are my custom functions in the File.php Model:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::deleting(function($file) {
        \Storage::disk('private')->delete($file->file);
    });
}

public function setFileAttribute($value)
{
    $attribute_name = "file";
    $disk = "private";
    $destination_path = "";
    // Cifratura del file
    file_put_contents($value->getRealPath(), file_get_contents($value->getRealPath()));
    $this->uploadFileToDisk($value, $attribute_name, $disk, $destination_path);
}
```

And here is my FileCRUDController.php code:

```
    $this->crud->addField(
    [   // Upload
        'name' => 'file',
        'label' => 'File to upload',
        'type' => 'upload',
        'upload' => true,
        'disk' => 'private'
    ]);
```

When i try to download the file, however, it tries to fetch it from http://localhost:8000/storage/myfile.png instead of http://localhost:8000/storage/private/myfile.png

What i'm doing wrong? Thank you very much.

I would also like to know if there is a way to hook a custom function instead downloading the file directly from the CRUD view. My files are encrypted and i need a controller that cares about decrypting before sending the files to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Method url() is still not usable for the files are placed in subdirectories.

You may also use the storage_path function to generate a fully qualified path to a given file relative to the storage directory:

```
$app_path = storage_path('app');
$file_path = storage_path('app/file.txt');
```

In reference to Issue [#13610](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13610#issuecomment-277743688)

The following works for version 5.3:

```
'my-disk' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root'   => storage_path(),
    'url'    => '/storage'
],

\Storage::disk('my-disk')->url('private/myfile.png')

this should return "/storage/private/myfile.png"
```